# Javascript if statement less than 'x' object in array don't show data

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I am showing related documents. I only want this to show if there is more than one related document in the array.

```
displayTable = function(data) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.results.data.length; i++) {
    if (data.results.data[i].length < 0) {
      console.log('dont show');
    } else if (data.results.data[i]) {
      data.push(data.results.data[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't `if (pubData.results.data[i].length < 0)` be `if (pubData.results.data[i].length < 1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pubData.results.data[i].length < 0` means less than ***zero***, not less than **one**.

Use `< 1` for less than one:

```
if (pubData.results.data[i].length < 1)
```

Or optionally `=== 0`, if it's a true array (the `length` of a true JavaScript array is never negative):

```
if (pubData.results.data[i].length === 0)
```

Or (again for a true array) you can use `!`:

```
if (!pubData.results.data[i].length)
```

Comment: I see you got there before me :)